# How to make h1 and h1 both render on the same line

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hello i got this problem with my logo and one text in wordpress.

I want my logo to have a text after it with this code that i use

```
                        <?php if ( $logoImg || $blogname ) { ?>
                            <div class="site-branding <?php if ( ! display_header_text() ) { echo 'hide-header-text'; } ?>">
                              
                                    <h1 class="site-logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo $logoImg; ?>" alt="logo" /></a></h1>
                                
                                   <h1 class="site-logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                                
                            </div>
```

And the result is this image [image: before]

And i want it to be like this

[image: After]

So i tried these codes

```
<h1 class="site-logo" style = "
display:inline;"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo $logoImg; ?>" alt="logo" /></a></h1>
                                    
                                       <h1 class="site-logo" style = "
display:inline;"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
```

And this one

```
<h1 class="site-logo" style="text-align:left;float:left;"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo $logoImg; ?>" alt="logo" /></a></h1>
                                
                                   <h1 class="site-logo" style="text-align:right;float:right;"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
```

But i had no luck.
Can someone help me?

Update 1:

The page is here

```
http://expertalbert.com/
```

And also i have tried to put it in one line

```
<h1 class="site-logo" style="display: inline;"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo $logoImg; ?>" alt="logo" /></a><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
```

And without the "display: inline" in the one line h1.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I would go for only 1 `h1` element, a left-hand padding and the logo as a background image.

Comment: Is there any chance we could get a link to where this is happening? There could be other styles at work causing this to happen.

Comment: @jeroen oh i also tried this one too.. i will update the answer for both

Comment: You should also really _really_ avoid those inline `style="..."` and create CSS style rules instead - preferably in a CSS file all of your pages can share, not a `<style>` block in the page. Inline styles are a maintenance _nightmare_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a `display: inline-block;` to your h1 elements

Answer (score 2):

Try using `display: flex` on the container:

```
#masthead .site-branding {
    display: flex;
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image]

---

For alignment options see: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: It actually does work on your site. Tested with Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: i put it on the style.css file and i refresh the home page...But still its not working

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios I did inspect your page and observed that this css is getting overwriiten with the other css you wrote in your site-banner.css. Disable the one you wrote in site-banner.css and check it out

Answer (score 2):

HTML block level elements (`display:block`) such as an `<h1>` can be made to display side-by-side in several ways.

`float`

Floating elements pulls them out of the page flow; to do this you have to float all elements that should appear together, and be sure to `clear` after the last one.

```
// css rule to float *all* site-logos left
h1.site-logo {
    float: left;
}
```

Floating messes up page flow, so for something simple like this there are better alternatives.

`flex layout`

Using flex layout gives you a lot of power, but there's too much to go into here... you should find [a tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) specifically about flex layout to learn all about it.
A simple start however, is just to set the display to `flex` or `inline-flex` ... **note** that you apply inline-flex to the *parent* container of the elements you want to arrange, so CSS would be

```
.site-branding {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Flex is well supported in newer browsers, so if you have to support older ones (such as IE9 which doesn't support flex) you probably would go with the last method I list, as an alternative to flex.

`inline-block`

Changing the display type from `block` to `inline-block` allows elements to display inline (next to each other) while retaining many block qualities, such as fixing the height and width. This would simply be

```
.site-logo {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

In all cases here, though, a logo is *not* really a level-1 heading so revised markup may be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to inspect the rest of your code to be able to tell you for sure how to fix this.  But I would float the image to the left or display everything as inline block. Then give your text a line height to match the height of the image. It should center the text nicely with your image.  Also you should only use one h1 tag on a page, for SEO purposes it is best practice to only have one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot you shared, I believe that

- Your first attempt did not work because there is not enough space for both elements to fit in one line which resulted in a line break
- your second attempt did not work because you did not appoint a width to your floating elements which can, [according to this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/), result in unpredictable behaviour

I, personally would nor recommend using two h1's on a page, neither using a h1 to wrap the logo of a website.

however, if you want your first attempt to work, just add `white-space: nowrap` to the element containing the logo and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try and make the image smaller by making the width less than one EM, or try with different pixel sizes, i.e `10px`,`5px`,etc;

```
  <h1 class="site-logo" style="width:.5em; text-align:left; float:left;"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="<?php echo   $logoImg; ?>" alt="logo" /></a></h1>
```

Comment: style="width:.5em;..."

Comment: Please don't add extra info in comments, instead edit your anser.